# Can this construction generate bounded aperiodic functions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, arithmetic-dynamics

This question is based on this old MathOverflow question: [How this set of functions is ordered?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82399/how-this-set-of-functions-is-ordered/)

In that question, Vladimir Reshetnikov asked about a class $S$ of functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ (note that $\mathbb{N}$ here includes $0$, this is important, because this is what allows us to do some rudimentary "programming" with this construction -- see my answer at the linked question) defined recursively as follows:

- The constant $0$, constant $1$, identity, and successor functions are in $S$
- Given $f,g,h\in S$, one has $n\mapsto f^{g(n)}(h(n))\in S$.

I've been thinking about this construction again and in particular have been wondering: Is there any function $f\in S$ which is bounded but not eventually periodic?

(Or, as I was originally thinking of it: What sets can we detect?  I.e. what functions can we construct in $S$ with image contained in $\{0,1\}$?  Can we detect any sets that are not eventually arithmetic progressions?  Like say the set of squares or the set of powers of $2$?  I don't see how to do either of those!)

I had originally hoped to prove there was not such a function, as part of an attempted proof that the predecessor function is not in $S$, but now I suspect that there is such an $f$; I even have a candidate for it, but the candidate seems difficult to analyze.

Specifically: Define $g(n)$ by $g(9q+r)=10\cdot2^q+r$, for $0\le r<9$.  Then let $f(n)=g^n(n) \bmod{6}$; this is a function in $S$ (I'll justify that below).  Doing some experiments, $g^n(0) \bmod{6}$ also seems to work, which might be easier to analyze, but I haven't really gotten anywhere with that either.

(I say "mod 6", but really either mod 2 or mod 3 individually should work.)

Anyway, that's the question and my candidate.  Below the bar I'll put more information (like why $f\in S$ or why I think $f$ might work).

---

Proof that $f\in S$: By the constructions used to answer the older question, we can construct $h\in S$ defined by $h(n)=2n-18$ if $n\equiv 8\pmod{10}$ and $h(n)=n+1$ otherwise.  Then $g(n)=h^n(10)$.  So therefore $f\in S$ and then again by the constructions used to answer the older question, we can mod out by $6$ (or whatever you like).

Why I think this candidate might work: My idea was as follows: The problem with iterating something of the form $n\mapsto a^n$ (to get a tetration type function) and then taking that modulo some $m$ is that $a^n$ mod $m$ depends on $n$ modulo $\phi(m)$, which for $m>1$, is less than $m$.  So after enough iterations it depends on $n$ modulo $1$, and things stabilize.  More generally I'm pretty sure that as long as the $g(n)$ that you're iterating depends, mod any given $m$, on $n$ modulo $m'$ where $m'\le m$ (for large enough $n$), you similarly get eventual periodicity, though the argument is more complicated and I didn't fully check it.  So, I figured, what if we could get a sequence of $m_0<m_1<m_2<\ldots$ such that $g(n)$ depends modulo $m_i$ on $n$ modulo $m_{i+1}$?  The idea is that the $g$ I defined above satisfies that, with $m_i=2\cdot3^{i+1}$.  Because, you see, modulo $3^k$, $2$ is a generator, with order $2\cdot3^{k-1}$, so I figured, if I can just slow things down by a factor of $9$, that should do it.

(I am eliding here the distinction between a modulus of $3^k$ and a modulus of $2\cdot 3^k$ but these are not very different for our purposes here.  I said above it should work mod $6$ but I was originally thinking of it as mod $3$.  The reason it should work mod $2$ is that its values mod $2$ depend on its values mod $9$, and mod $9$ it should similarly lack any eventual period.)

Comment: One simple bounded aperiodic function uses the fact that every positive integer $n$ can be written as $n=3^kb$ with $3\nmid b$; one can then define $f(3^kb)=b\mod3$ (and define $f(0)$ however you want). Can this function be realized as a member of your $S$?

Comment: As mentioned, I don't know how to detect powers of $2$.  This doesn't seem any easier than that.